# How to print day of the date without using inbuilt calendar date day packages, libraries in java

Tags: java

In this program i want to print day of the date without using inbuilt calendar packages.. And i'm not able to get exact answer for certain dates (input date). in this i get day of the date correctly for only upto 31.12.0004. Note that it is the assessment given by my guide 5 days before still i'm not getting correct answer and I'm not supposed to use calendar packages and api's because syllabus for my course completed lists : basic array, if & else, for loops, class and objects.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class calendarr
{
public static void main(String arg[])
    {
int z=0;
do{
    int id,im,iy;
    Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter DD MM YYYY : ");
    id = ip.nextInt();
    im = ip.nextInt();
    iy = ip.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");

    int totalDays = 0, leapYearDays = 366, ordinaryYearDays = 365, y = iy-1,day=0;
    int totalDaysOfGivenYear,totalDaysUptoGivenMonth=0, totalDaysEntire;
    int leapYearCount = y%4, ordinaryYearCount = y - leapYearCount;
    int totalDaysUptoPreviousYear=0;
    int totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount = (leapYearCount * leapYearDays)+(ordinaryYearCount * ordinaryYearDays);
    System.out.print("Odd Days Leap Year and Ordinary Year : "+leapYearCount+" "+ordinaryYearCount+"\n");


    String[] months = new String[] {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
    int[] monthDates = new int[] {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    String[] weekDays = new String[] {"Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};


        if((iy%4==0)&&(iy%100!=0)||(iy%400==0))
            {
            monthDates[2] = 29;
            System.out.println("It is Leap Year");
            }
        else System.out.println("It is Ordinary Year");

    for(int i=1;i<=monthDates.length;i++)
        {


        totalDays = totalDays + monthDates[i-1];
        }
    for(int j=1;j<=im;j++)
        {
        totalDaysUptoGivenMonth = totalDaysUptoGivenMonth+monthDates[j];

        }
        totalDaysOfGivenYear = totalDaysUptoGivenMonth+id-monthDates[im];

        System.out.println("Total Days Upto Given Months : "+totalDaysOfGivenYear+"\nTotal Days of given year :  "+iy+" : "+totalDays);


        System.out.println("Total Count : "+totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount);


        //totalDaysEntire = totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount - totalDays+ totalDaysOfGivenYear;
        totalDaysEntire = totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount+ totalDaysOfGivenYear-y;
        System.out.println("Overall Total Days : "+totalDaysEntire);


    /*//day = (365+366-totalDays+totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount)%7;

        for(int k=0;k<=y;k++)
        {

        day = (totalDaysEntire%7);



        System.out.println(day+"\n"+weekDays[day]+"\n\n");
        }*/

    day = ((totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount+ totalDaysOfGivenYear-iy)%7);

    System.out.println(day+"\n"+weekDays[day]+"\n\n");
}
while(z<5); 

    }
}
```

output: Enter DD MM YYYY : 1 1 1
Odd Days Leap Year and Ordinary Year : 0 0
It is Ordinary Year
Total Days Upto given month : 1
Total days of given year : 1 : 365
Total Count : 0
Overall Total Days : 1
0
Saturday

Comment: Can you provide example output? What are you supposed to get and what are you getting.

Comment: output: Enter DD MM YYYY : 1 1 1 Odd Days Leap Year and Ordinary Year : 0 0 It is Ordinary Year Total Days Upto given month : 1 Total days of given year : 1 : 365 Total Count : 0 Overall Total Days : 1 0 Saturday

Answer (score 1):

Hey there were some fixes required in your code check this code it works now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calendarr
{
public static void main(String arg[])
    {
int z=0;
do{
    int id,im,iy;
    Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter DD MM YYYY : ");
    id = ip.nextInt();
    im = ip.nextInt();
    iy = ip.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");

    int totalDays = 0, leapYearDays = 366, ordinaryYearDays = 365, y = iy-1,day=0;
    int totalDaysOfGivenYear,totalDaysUptoGivenMonth=0, totalDaysEntire;
    int leapYearCount = 0;
    //calculate the number of leap and non leap years
    for(int i=0;i<=y;i++){
        if((i%4==0)&&(i%100!=0)||(i%400==0))
            {
                leapYearCount++;
            }
    }
    int ordinaryYearCount = y - leapYearCount;
    int totalDaysUptoPreviousYear=0;
    int totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount = (leapYearCount * leapYearDays)+(ordinaryYearCount * ordinaryYearDays);
    System.out.print("Odd Days Leap Year and Ordinary Year : "+leapYearCount+" "+ordinaryYearCount+"\n");


    String[] months = new String[] {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
    int[] monthDates = new int[] {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    String[] weekDays = new String[] {"Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};

 if((iy%4==0)&&(iy%100!=0)||(iy%400==0))
            {
            monthDates[2] = 29;
            System.out.println("It is Leap Year");
            }
        else System.out.println("It is Ordinary Year");

    for(int i=1;i<=monthDates.length;i++)
        {
        totalDays = totalDays + monthDates[i-1];
        }
    for(int j=1;j<im;j++)
        {
        totalDaysUptoGivenMonth = totalDaysUptoGivenMonth+monthDates[j];

        }
        totalDaysOfGivenYear = totalDaysUptoGivenMonth+id;

        System.out.println("Total Days Upto Given Months : "+totalDaysOfGivenYear+"\nTotal Days of given year :  "+iy+" : "+totalDays);


        System.out.println("Total Count : "+totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount);


        //totalDaysEntire = totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount - totalDays+ totalDaysOfGivenYear;
        totalDaysEntire = totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount+ totalDaysOfGivenYear;
        System.out.println("Overall Total Days : "+totalDaysEntire);


    /*//day = (365+366-totalDays+totalDaysUptoPreviousYearCount)%7;

        for(int k=0;k<=y;k++)
        {

        day = (totalDaysEntire%7);



        System.out.println(day+"\n"+weekDays[day]+"\n\n");
        }*/

    day = (totalDaysEntire%7);

    System.out.println(day+"\n"+weekDays[day]+"\n\n");
}
while(z<5); 

    }
}
```

I had changed some things moved the setting the days of feb out of loop. Check the calculation for the number of years and non leap years . And also did the changes on finding `totalDaysOfGivenYear`, `totalDaysEntire` and the `day` variables.

**Input** : 1 1 1998

**output:**

```
Odd Days Leap Year and Ordinary Year : 485 1512
It is Ordinary Year
Total Days Upto Given Months : 1
Total Days of given year :  1998 : 365
Total Count : 729390
Overall Total Days : 729391
5
Thursday
```